# Synchronous Kafka Producer - How to ensure a message was successfully delivered to kafka broker after future get method is called

Tags: java, apache-kafka

```
 try{
 RecordMetadata d = producer.send(message).get()
 if(d.hasoffset()){
 //only way to ensure kafka was sent??
 }}
 catch (Exception e){
 //or does this alone guarentee the message was sent 
 }
```

does the catch exception alone ensure the message was sent or is some if statement check required

Answer (score 0):

You should set `acks=1` or `acks=all` to ensure a broker gets the messages.

After that, then if `.get()` does not throw an exception, then the broker will have the record.

You'll also want to ensure the `min.insync.replicas` on the topics are at least 1.